# SharePoint list calculated column 3 validations for IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I have a SP list that contains software installation data. There is a calculated column that calculates price. There is a column called Installation Date which has 2 choices either Before Sep 30, 2020 or After Sep 30, 2020 in String. There is a request type field which has 2 choices New or Renew. The Charge Date field contains Date.

I created this formula which works but is missing the logic to filter Request Type field. I wanted some assistance on updating the IF statement.

```
=IF([Installation Date]="Before Sep 30, 2020",[Lic Qty]*750,(([Lic Qty]*430)/TEXT([Charge Date],"mm")))
```

1. For Software installed before Sep 30, 2020 and Request Type is New: cost will be $750
2. For Software installed before Sep 30, 2020 and Request Type is Renew: cost will be $430
3. For Software installed After Sep 30, 2020 : Price will be $430 per license per year. Pro-rated for the current year.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF([Installation Date]="Before Sep 30, 2020",IF([Request Type]="New",[Lic Qty]*750,[Lic Qty]*430),([Lic Qty]*430)/MONTH([Charge Date]))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Microsoft official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're after. To make it a bit simpler, I've reversed your logic. Instead of starting with the "Before" scenario, I've started with the "After", which means I don't need to use multiple conditions.

```
=IF([Installation Date] = "After Sep 30, 2020",([Lic Qty] * 430) / Month([Charge Date]),IF([Request Type] = "New", [Lic Qty] * 750, [Lic Qty] * 430))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see, this is a great way to do it :)